# How do I use validates_numericality_of with a decimal field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a table with a column (dose) that is defined as a decimal. When the user fills out the form field for this column I want to make sure they enter a valid number. I want to use `validates_numericality_of :dose` but this doesn't work. If the user enters a non-numeric value (e.g. 'horse') a value of 0 is saved to the database and the validation is passed. I would prefer an error was raised.

Is there a way of catching this earlier in the object lifecycle? At what point is active record converting the string to a 0?

Answer (score 1):

My expectation would be that you have another plugin or hook or something that's getting in the way and changing the value before validation.

To maybe get some more insight as to what the situation is, add a before_validation hook to the model and raise self.inspect to see what the object looks like right before the validations fire. Try to save an instance with text in the :dose attribute and see what it looks like.

Comment: OK, weird. I explored this and did the before_validation/self.inspect as suggested. The output showed the text in the :dose attribute was indeed being converted to a 0 (actually 0.0 - which is what should have been in my question). This is what you get from BigDecimal.new("horse") so it isn't actually surprising. What's weird is that the validation is currently working. I don't know why it's working now and not before though.

Comment: Schroedinger's Bug - once you look at it, it ceases to exist. ;)